# ESLint "Parsing error: ',' expected." when using TypeScript satisfies operator

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm trying to use TypeScript's new satisfies operator to keep the most specific type for a variable in my code, but ESLint is throwing a `Parsing error: ',' expected.` error on the closing curly bracket of the object when I add `satisfies Prisma.gameInclude;` to the end of it.

Here's how the object in question looks:

```
const includeFields = {
  participants: true,
  queue: {
    include: {
      gamemode: {
        include: {
          character_pool: {
            include: {
              characters: true,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
} satisfies Prisma.gameInclude;
^ Parsing error: ',' expected.
```

And here's my `.eslintrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  overrides: [],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "unused-imports"],
  rules: {
    "unused-imports/no-unused-imports": "error",
  },
};
```

I've tried adding the `parserOptions.project` property to it pointing to my tsconfig, but no luck.

Reading through some PRs and issues for typescript-eslint I found our that [it does already support the satisfies operator](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/5717). I'm currently on its latest version, 5.56.0.

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you manage to fix this bro? i'm having the same problem with `tailwind.config.ts` in an electron-forge app. help

edit: nevermind, i restarted vscode and it fix my problem after updating typescript. thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, that's embarassing. I found the cause of the error a few minutes after posting this question.

Upon checking the `package.json` for this project I found out that `typescript` was on version **4.3.5**. [The satisfies operator was added on TypeScript 4.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator).

Updating TS to its newest version, **5.0.2**, fixed the issue.

Comment: Where do you change it? I don't have any typescript version specified in package.json or tsconfig.json, and I just updated typescript-eslint to latest version. Still have the same issue.

Comment: You can `npm install typescript@VERSION --save-dev` to install a specific version.

Comment: did try updating typescript to latest but didn't work.

edit: i think vscode needs to restart first. it did fix my problem. sorry and thanks!!

Comment: Also worked for me, but you also may need to upgrade prettier package.